# Problems with mutex and conditional variable

Tags: visual-c++, conditional-statements, mutex

I'm trying to make a simple program that uses one thread, mutex and unique lock.

I'm trying to synchronize the Main loop and the Thread loop like this:
The main loop prints "M" one time, then the Thread loop prints "T" (and so on).
I'm trying to make conditional variable and Unique Lock but I get errors in the Thread's function when trying to lock/unlock the mutex.
Could somebody try to help me?
It only prints the Main's loop - "M"

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

mutex update_mtx; // lock for updating information //
condition_variable cv;

void foo()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> key(update_mtx);
    int len = 5;
    while (len != 0)
    {
        cv.wait(key);   
        update_mtx.lock();
        cout << "T";
        update_mtx.unlock();
        len--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int len = 5;
    thread first(foo);
    while (len != 0){
        update_mtx.lock();
        cout << "M";
        update_mtx.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
        len--;
    }
    first.join();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `cv.wait(key)` returns, the mutex is locked. By trying to lock it again, your program exhibits undefined behavior. Drop `lock()` and `unlock()` calls in `foo`.

Comment: Another problem - for all you know, `main` may run through the loop all the way to `join()` before the first instruction of `foo` gets to execute. `notify_all()` is a no-op when no one is waiting to be notified. Then you'll have a deadlock.

Comment: `std::condition_variable` is supposed to protect a condition - some kind of invariant. For example, a boolean flag that indicates whose turn it is to write. You can't use `std::condition_variable` the way you try to, without actually checking the condition and looping until it becomes true - because a) spurious wake-ups are possible (that is, `wait()` may return even though no one called `notify*`), and b) `notify*` may be lost if no one waits at that precise moment.

Comment: [See demo](http://rextester.com/RHO21633)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , ok Igor, I understand what was my problem.
Thank you very much !